# Forwarding a call received on mobile network via a voip app

Tags: android

I have a office phone (Phone 1) without international calling. I have another smartphone sitting at home (not allowed at work) (Phone 2) with apps for international calling. Is there an app that can do the following?

1. I call the smartphone from my office phone.
2. The smart phone should then use any app (like ringo, hangouts dialer, viber, etc..) to make a call to a prefixed international number
3. And I should be able to talk from my phone 1